# Understanding why the space of $L^2$-bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$ is incomplete

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

So I have just started a course which threw us right into the space that contains all continuous real valued functions. In other words, for $1 \leq p <\infty$, consider
$$\left\{ f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \, : \, f \text{ is continuous, }\int_{R^n} |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty \right\} $$

Now, I want to see why this space is incomplete. Here is a piece of work that I am reading and trying to understand. Could someone break it down for me?
[image]
There is a couple of things I don't understand. One is where is the upper bound $4 \times \frac{2}{k}$ coming from? Also what is the limit of this seq? How do I know it doesn't exist in the space itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to see that it is not complete is to notice that if $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $\|\cdot\|_p$ then $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So essentially any $\|\cdot\|_p$ limit must also be a pointwise limit.

Now if you look at your example it  is not too hard to see that $f^{(k)}$ converges pointwise to a function that is not continuous, therefore any $\|\cdot\|_p$ limit point of the sequence must be equal to this non-continuous function, and thus it is not in $A$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that was awesome. Could you expand a bit on pointwise onvergence bit? What is the importance of saying "almost all $x$ in R"

Comment: @TylerHilton Elements of $L^p$ are defined as equivalence classes of functions that differ by measure zero sets.

Comment: I have not taken any measure theory. Is there another way to describe the elements of $L^p$

Comment: You could describe this in the way that this problem is leading you to. (ie as the completetion of continuous functions with this metric. So this would mean describing them as certain equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of continuous functions. This is more cumbersome that the description mentioned by Potato.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $C = \{ f | f \text{ is continuous},\, \int |f|^2 < \infty \}$ with the norm $\|f\| = \sqrt{\int |f|^2}$.

Let $f_k(x) = \begin{cases} \operatorname{sgn} x, & |x|> \frac{1}{k} \\
kx, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. Then it should be clear that $f_k \in C$ for all $k$.

Now suppose $n>m\ge N$ and evaluate $\|f_n-f_m \|^2 $ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
\|f_n-f_m \|^2 &=& \int |f_n-f_m|^2 \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2 dx \\
&=& 2 \int_{0}^\infty |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2 dx \\
&=& 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{m}} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2 dx \\
&=& 2 ( \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2 dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{m}} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|^2 dx) \\
&=& 2 ( \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} (nx-mx)^2 dx + \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{m}} (1-mx)^2 dx) \\
&=& 2(\frac{(n-m)^2}{3 n^3} + \frac{(n-m)^3}{3 m n^3}) \\
& \le & 2 ( \frac{n^2}{3 n^3} + \frac{n^3}{3 m n^3} ) \\
&=& \frac{2}{3}(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{m}) \\
&\le & \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{N}
\end{eqnarray}
from which it follows that the sequence $f_n$ is Cauchy.

Proving that $f_n$ does not converge to a member of $C$ is a bit tedious. We proceed by contradiction and suppose the sequence converges to some $f \in C$.
The idea is to show that for $x \neq 0$, we must have $f(x) = \operatorname{sgn} x$, which contradicts $f \in C$.

Choose $x > 0$, and suppose $f(x) \neq 1$. Since $f$ is continuous, we have some $\epsilon>0$ and some $\delta >0$ such that $|f(y)-1| \ge \epsilon$ for  all $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$. (We can assume that $0 < x-\delta$.)
For $n$ sufficiently large, we have $f_n(y) =1$ for all $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$. Then we have the estimate $ \|f_n-f\|^2 \ge \int_{(x-\delta, x+\delta)} |f(y)-1|^2 dy \ge 2 \epsilon^2 \delta >0$, which contradicts the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. Hence $f(x) = 1$. Similarly we have $f(x) = -1$ for $x <0$. However, this contradicts $f \in C$, hence $f_n$ cannot converge to an element of $C$.